# Underlying C++ instance of a PyQt4 object isn't deleted at function's end, but it is deleted right after return

Tags: pyqt, return, python-sip

I used `sip.isdeleted(obj)` in the conditions of two conditional breakpoints (the function `isdeleted` refers to exactly the same object in both cases) - one appears at the last line of a function, and the other appears at the line following the function's call.
During debug, the program doesn't break at the first line (last line of the function) and breaks in the second (following the call). How can it be?

Comment: Please show some real code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The code is too complex. This is a part of a bug in a quite big project. My question is: Is it possible/reasonable that such a scenario will happen? What can cause it?

Comment: But what "scenario"? The more clearly you [define the problem](http://sscce.org/), the greater the chances you will have of getting good answers.

Comment: It's too complex for me to define the problem with a small code.